# Git enforce commit of file pairs

Tags: git, githooks, git-commit

In my git repository I have a file `workflow.vsd` that represents a diagram created in Microsoft Visio.

Since not everybody in our team has Visio installed, whoever changes the `workflow.vsd` must also generate a correspondent `workflow.png`.

The problem is that quite often, people commit a new version of the `vsd` file and forget to commit the `png`, making the image outdated.

Is there some way for git to allow a commit only if both `workflow.vsd` and `workflow.png` are added under the same commit hash?

In other words, I want to commit the Visio project only and only if png is also commited:

```
git add workflow.vsd worflow.png
git commit
```

and this should fail:

```
git add workflow.vsd
git commit
```

Comment: You can use a pre-commit hook to check whether your commit matches your rules, but everyone must install their own pre-commit hook. If you have a central server where you can install hooks, you can set up a pre-receive hook that rejects pushes that do not match your rules. If you use a pull workflow, you can reject pull requests that do not match your rules. Combinations of some or all of these are also possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to look in to commit hooks - Git allows access to several points of the process, one of which being pre-commit, in which you can inject some code.

You'll be able to check for those files with something along the lines of
`git status -s | grep "workflow.vsd"`.

You could then either also check for the `png` and fail if it isn't present, or run a script which automatically generates the `png` as escitalopram suggests.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend against that setup. Users shouldn't be required to put generated stuff into version control. In programming we have build tools to automatically generate derived files from »source files« such as the vsd. Maybe you can look into Makefiles or Maven or whatever build tool you see fit (although I don't know if there's a tool to make pngs from vsds).

If you must have the png in versioning, the other way to go around it would be a [commit hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks), either on »the git server« or on the local repositories. Still, you need to have a tool that can automatically generate pngs.

If you don't have the tool either, you can still write a commit hook that checks programmatically if both files have been changed or not, and reject the commit if necessary.

Comment: I agree with you, as I usually use build tools to generate such files. But in this case, upper management decided otherwise, since some of them still have old versions of Office (without Visio) and want the convenience of seeing the flow directly on the browser, when they click a bitbucket link.